# Ocaml compiling list comprehensions

Tags: ocaml, list-comprehension

I want to use ocamlopt to compile list comprehensions.  I do not want to use any special libraries, since ocaml supports list comprehensions at least at the top (interactive) level.

Marko Tunjic posted :

list comprehension is already included in standard ocaml

```
#require "camlp4.listcomprehension";;

[ x * x | x <- [ 1;2;3;4;5] ];;

- : int list = [1; 4; 9; 16; 25]
```

On ocaml 4.07.1 I found that the following is required on interactive:

```
#use "topfind";;
#camlp4o;;
#require "camlp4.listcomprehension";;
```

file lc1.ml contains

```
open Camlp4.ListComprehensions

let _ = [ x * y | x <- [ 1;2;3;4;5]; y <- [10;11;12;13;14 ] ];;
```

## compile

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -package camlp4 -linkpkg lc1.ml -o lc1

File "lc1.ml", line 3, characters 16-17:
Error: Syntax error
```

## expected results

```
[10; 11; 12; 13; 14; 20; 22; 24; 26; 28; 30; 33; 36; 39; 42; 40; 44;      48; 52;
 56; 50; 55; 60; 65; 70]
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all a disclaimer. Camlp4 is deprecated so I would highly discourage to use it in any new project. Consider using ppx, or if you really need something that ppx is not able to provide to you, then camlp5 is still at your service.

To build a program that is written in a non-standard OCaml syntax, you need to explicitly tell `ocamlfind` which syntax you're using, e.g., `-syntax camlp4o`. This is analogous to the `#camlp4o` directive of the `topfind` utility, that you were using.

Next, you don't need to open anything (the `open` statement in OCaml just extends the current namespace with definitions from the opened module). There is no such module as `Camlp4.ListComprehensions`, therefore, the correct version of your program is

```
let _ = [ x * y | x <- [ 1;2;3;4;5]; y <- [10;11;12;13;14 ] ]
```

and here is the build command

```
ocamlfind ocamlopt -syntax camlp4o -package camlp4.listcomprehension -linkpkg lc1.ml -o lc1
```

Comment: The toplevel interactive use of list comprehensions does not work on ocaml 4.09.0:              opam install camlp4
The following dependencies couldn't be met:
  - camlp4 → ocaml < 4.09
      base of this switch (use `--unlock-base' to force)
  - camlp4 → ocaml-variants (= 4.02.0+modular-implicits & =
    4.02.1+modular-implicits-ber)
      no matching version

Comment: List comprehension is really not part of the ocaml language, as it is in F#.  So will avoid ocaml list comprehensions.

Comment: Yes, it is not a part of the language, moreover, camlp4 is deprecated and is no longer released or maintained. And indeed, it is a good solution to ignore list comprehensions in OCaml.